# Read_CSV Parse Hidden DateTime Elements

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I'm having trouble parsing my data properly onto a pandas dataframe because my time is being read wrong.

Here's my data from a .csv. The Time is Hours:Minutes:Seconds.Milliseconds.

```
Date,Time,Volts
2015-08-26,05:43:59.998,-1.1925e-004
2015-08-26,05:44:00.003,-1.2245e-004
2015-08-26,05:44:00.008,-1.2139e-004
```

And here's my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',

            parse_dates={'TimeStamp': ['Date','Time']},
            index_col='TimeStamp',
            usecols=['Date', 'Time', 'Volts'],
            na_values=['0'],
           )

In [47]: df[:3]

Out[47]:
                 Volts
datetime    
8/26/15 44:00.0 -0.000119
8/26/15 44:00.0 -0.000122
8/26/15 44:00.0 -0.000121
```

As you can see, the Hour and the Millisecond element disappears and pandas rounds my first time value up, making it look like all the datetimes are the same. My question is, is it a matter of just changing display output options or is it parsing my dates erroneously?

Comment: This parses fine in pandas 0.16.2, which version are you using? Look at the df.index to check it's a DatetimeIndex.

Comment: I'm using the latest version. Thanks for the tip, it helped me troubleshoot my .csv, which ended up being corrupted so I had to pull from my backup.